# Upload multiples images

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to upload the same image twice in the same iteration. Not sure why, but with the code bellow I only got the upload for the first `save()`. The second I still have the file in directory, but the image has 0 bytes.

```
path_for_images_large = os.path.join(current_app.static_folder, "uploads/gallery/"+str(company.id)+"/large/")
path_for_images_small = os.path.join(current_app.static_folder, "uploads/gallery/"+str(company.id)+"/small/")
```

---

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for key, f in request.files.items():
        if key.startswith('file'):
            f.save(os.path.join(path_for_images_small, f.filename))
            f.save(os.path.join(path_for_images_large, f.filename))
```

Comment: as I know server downloads file to temporary folder and `save()` moves file from temporary folder to your folder. After first `save()` temporary folder can be empty so second `save()` has nothing to move. You could copy `f.filename` to second folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first saving you are at the end of the file and there is nothing to write, type `f.seek(0)` to move to the start.

```
    f.save(os.path.join(path_for_images_small, f.filename))
    f.seek(0)    
    f.save(os.path.join(path_for_images_large, f.filename))
```